# NTC to multiple inputs

Tags: temperature, thermistor

I have one NTC thermister from which I want to send the output to two different controllers. Is this possible, or does it affect the accuracy?

To be more specific, my Land Rover has one NTC coolant temperature sender, which is connected to the Water Temperature gauge. I'm adding electric fans, so I also want to send the temperature to the fan controller. Can I simply tap the two wires and connect them to the fan controller without affecting accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I simply tap the two wires and connect them to the fan controller without affecting accuracy?

No, you cannot.

A thermister is a variable resistance. In order to read its value, a controller must send a current through the thermister and measure the resulting voltage across it (or something equivalent to that).

Therefore, if you connect one thermister to two different controllers, each one will be trying to apply current, and you'll end up with twice the intended current through the device and twice the voltage, which will give a completely wrong temperature reading.

In order to do this correctly, you need to allow one of the controllers to function normally, and then buffer the resulting voltage for the second controller, taking into account the fact that the second controller might be using a different value for its sense current, which would require the voltage to be scaled accordingly. The current might not be a constant value, as well.

One or both controllers might not even have one end of the thermister connected to ground (or any other shareable reference node), further complicating matters.

In other words, you need to know a lot about how both controllers work internally before you can consider how to get them to share a sensor.

Answer (score -2):

If you use an OpAmp buffer, feeding an ADC/MCU or just into an analog comparator, you will not load the NTC.

Look for "CMOS" inputs on the OpAmp or Comparator.

For extra ESD protection and some RFI rejection, insert a 10Kohm resistor and 0.01uF cap between NTC and your circuits, with the cap taken to Ground right at your OpAmp or Comparator (that is, share the VIA used by the VDD bypass cap of your analog frontend).

{EDIT} I'd place the 10Kohm right next to the NTC. Otherwise your new wiring will alter the EMI/RFI susceptibility. Is the vehicle still under warrantee?

Comment: This area is reserved for answers to the question at the top of the page. Your answer seems to be addressing a question about constructing a controller from scratch. To request clarification or critique a post, leave a comment below it.

Comment: His first sentence is about monitoring the NTC voltage output, without upsetting the NTC performance. I intended to address that.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, and thanks for that... it's an '86 vehicle, warrantee is loooong gone. :). The NTC is mounted in the engine bay in quite a hostile environment. Not entirely sure how big this circuit would be (=where to mount, if not on the NTC), and also, how reliable (=it's quite important to have this reading fairly accurate), so I'm probably going with simply a second NTC for the fans. But it's very interesting what you're saying nonetheless, and like to investigate this option further.